# How to validate multiple select in Laravel

Tags: laravel, validation

I have a multiple select in my form :

```
<div class="col-sm-9">
  {!! Form::select('live_in[]', $cities, null, ['placeholder' => '-----', 'class' => 'form-control', 'multiple' => true]) !!}
  @if ($errors->has('live_in'))
    <span class="help-block m-b-none">{{$errors->first('live_in')}}</span>
  @endif
</div>
```

and in `Http/Requests/AddCityRequest.php` I have this rule :

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'live_in' => 'required',
            ...
        ];
    }
```

but because I have `placeholder` in select, when user don't select any items the rules no work.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a placeholder for your select. Instead push an option into the array at the first index with no value, like this:

```
<option value=""> -------- </option>
```

This will not send the value to the server, so the rule will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel doesn't have much of a validator for array size validation. Here's a custom one:

```
$this->app['validator']->extend('min_array_size', function($attribute, $value, $parameters) {

        $data = $value;

        if( ! is_array($data)){
            return true;
        }
        return count($data) >= $parameters[0];
});
```

Put those peace of code in `App\Providers\AppServiceProvider`'s boot method

and to use them try something like this.

```
'some_array' => 'array|min_array_size:2'
```